# Selective package update Nuget

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, proget

We have just started publishing to an internal nuget feed using Proget. The projects are built in CI (Teamcity) but the assembly version numbers do not change just the informational version. I have recently come to understand that setting the informational version overrides using the assembly version to name the nuget package. We currently have a nupkg versioning scheme of major.minor.patch.buildNumber.

This should mean that a newer build should be represented as a potential update

There are two questions

1. How do we do selective nuget updates in CI. For example we have third party packages like Moq and we want to keep those versions static whilst letting builds update the internally built packages to the latest available.
2. In the same vein, how do we do it on a local machine?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you without deleting the same version from the packages directory, and additionally the NuGet cache (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache`). The root problem here is that you want a package to be both a different version and also not a different version at the same time.

What are the real reasons behind the conscious decision to keep the same version number even though the binaries are different? This is usually a symptom of a kink in the deployment process that could be improved with automation.

Comment: thanks for reading, clarified my question with new information